# Automatic scroll multiple Divs with table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have multiple tables inside Divs that I want to autoscroll. 
I'm using this snippet.

```
$(".divDetail").each(function(){

 var div = document.getElementById($(this).attr("id"));

   setInterval(function () {

            // make sure it's not at the    bottom
            if (div.scrollTop < div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight)
                div.scrollTop += 2; // move down
            else
            { div.scrollTop = 0; }
        }, 100);  // 100 milliseconds

})
```

which works but why this selector does not work?

```
$(".divDetail").each(function(){

 var div = $(this);
   setInterval(function () {

            // make sure it's not at the    bottom
            if (div.scrollTop < div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight)
                div.scrollTop += 2; // move down
            else
            { div.scrollTop = 0; }
        }, 100);  // 100 milliseconds

})
```

[Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/czcz/4x4L1tjd/1/) and snippet below:

```js
var div = $("#tbl1");

setInterval(function() {

  // make sure it's not at the    bottom
  if (div.scrollTop < div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight)
    div.scrollTop += 2; // move down
  else {
    div.scrollTop = 0;
  }
}, 100); // 100 milliseconds
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tbl1" class="divDetail" style="overflow-y:auto; height:50px;">
  <table class="table table-border">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>STORE</th>
        <th>PALLETS</th>
        <th>ZONE</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>item</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You are not getting the ID of the `this` element.

Comment: so i'm just getting the object right? I would need something like     var div = $(this).attr("id");? but when I do that the script does not work.

Comment: Exactly. That's what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, your variable `div` contains a native element, in the second one, it's a jQuery object, and therefore doesn't have the same attributes/methods available. This will work.

```
$(".divDetail").each(function(){

 var div = $(this)[0];
   setInterval(function () {

            // make sure it's not at the    bottom
            if (div.scrollTop < div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight)
                div.scrollTop += 2; // move down
            else
            { div.scrollTop = 0; }
        }, 100);  // 100 milliseconds

})
```

Comment: thanks but what does [0] do? is that an index property?

Comment: @causita That's how you can retrieve the native element that's wrapped by the jQuery object. And because scrollTop and scrollHeight and clientHeight are properties of native elements, you need to work with a native element

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$(this)[0]` like this:

```js
var div = $("#tbl1")[0];

     setInterval(function() {

       // make sure it's not at the    bottom
       if (div.scrollTop < div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight)
         div.scrollTop += 2; // move down
       else {
         div.scrollTop = 0;
       }
     }, 100); // 100 milliseconds
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tbl1" class="divDetail" style="overflow-y:auto; height:50px;">
  <table class="table table-border">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>STORE</th>
        <th>PALLETS</th>
        <th>ZONE</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>item</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
        <td>dkd</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[UPDATED JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2p1dfz42/)